# Add a button to jQuery-Knob slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, round-slider

I need your help. I'm working on the project where necessary to implement a circular slider with draggable button-control by it. I decided to use [this jQuery-Knob slider](https://github.com/aterrien/jQuery-Knob). it's great but I need to add button that could be possible to set styles and be dragged

I made a decision to add div element through javascript and then tie native Jquery Knob params of dragging to it.

Here what I have done

[image]

And here is my code

```
function addBtnControl(self) {
              // cache variables
              var button = document.getElementById('knob-ctrl'),
                  cx = 22*self.scale,
                  cy = 20*self.scale,
                  a = self.arc(self.cv),
                  start = xyOnArc(self.xy-cx, self.xy-cy, self.radius/self.scale, a.s);

              // check if pointer-events are supported
              // if not than use fallback btn ctrl for IE
              App.config.Modernizr.addTest('csspointerevents',function(){
                return 'pointerEvents' in document.documentElement.style;
              });
              if (App.config.Modernizr.csspointerevents) {
                self.cursorExt = 0;

                button.style.left = start.x + "px";
                button.style.top = start.y + "px";
              }

              function xyOnArc(cx, cy, radius, radianAngleX) {
                var x = cx + radius * Math.cos(radianAngleX);
                var y = cy + radius * Math.sin(radianAngleX);
                return ({
                    x: x,
                    y: y
                });
              }
            }

            // init Button Ctrl

            addBtnControl(this);
```

I dynamically added a button and borrowed params that must be enough to make a well-suited draggable control but I've been doing something wrong because if I scale a browser or just open on another screen size it looks like this

So something wrong with the functions and params that passed to it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually jQuery knob was using Canvas, so adding external layers with it makes more complex.

Alternatively i suggest to use the jQuery [**roundSlider**](http://roundsliderui.com/) plugin which is similar to knob, but it constructs based on the **div** elements only. So you can make any custom appearances as per your wish.

For more details check the [demos](http://roundsliderui.com/demos.html) and [documentation](http://roundsliderui.com/document.html) page.

Check this demo from [**`jsFiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/LpuLe9tr/11/) which is similar to your requirement.

**Screenshot of the Output:**

[image: jquery round slider - custom appearances]

Comment: Yes, thanks, it's a great plugin. But for that moment when I wrote this post I think it's wasn't yet. 

So I used what I had and fixed that problem at the end but roundSlider is really good, it's much easier to create such stuff, thanks for sharing.